Simultaneously processing in node red
I have this flow in node red that receives via mqtt 1 or 0. These values are generated by a python script that reads a json object that indicates what times a machine should start operating.
However when I need the two machines to start operating at the same time it only starts machine 2. The functions are almost the same since the machines are pretty much the same so I don´t know what I can do in order to be sure that I will be able to start both machines simultaneously when I need them to do so.

I know machine 1 works since I have tested a non simultaneous approach

There is not enough information here to help. We need a lot more information, e.g. What is in your subflows?
